# Populating the values in an excel table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to work out a way to populate values in an excel table dependent on a range, for example, I have two tables:

[image]

I want to populate the Group number based on a look-up table:

[image]

So for any ID number that is between the `Min` and the `Max` ID in Table2, to get the Group number for that range, so in the Example tables above:

- John would get Group number 1
- Peter and Alex would get 2
- Dani would get 3

Table2 would be updated regularly and may grow in size as well.

I don't even know how to search for this properly, so apologies if this has already been answered elsewhere.. Any advise would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Use either `VLOOKUP()` Function with approximate match or just `LOOKUP()` Function

Comment: Refer this query on how to do an approximate match using either `VLOOKUP()` or `LOOKUP()` or `XLOOKUP()` Functions [Lookup Value based on Range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71876296/lookup-value-based-on-range)

Answer (score 0):

Use `INDEX()/MATCH()` combination with match mode `less than` option. Try-

```
=INDEX($I$3:$I$5,MATCH(B3,$G$3:$G$5,1))
```

If you are on Microsoft 365 then can use `XLOOKUP()`

```
=XLOOKUP(B3,$G$3:$G$5,$I$3:$I$5,"",-1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use Vlookup in the 4th parameter use True or 1 instead of False or 0.